# reset all fields in an android activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android, I have a requirement in my application.An app has two activities (Activity1, Activity2). Activity2 will be started from Activity1 on certain conditions (user selections).When we press back button in Activity2. It is navigating to Activity1 but the previous user selection is remain same. I want to clear the user selection when coming back to Activity1, how can i achieve this?

Comment: just reset selections before start new activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling activity2 with Intent from activity1
add following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this,activity2.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

and add this code to activity2 override metho
d

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity2.this,activity1.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Several Options**

**1.** you can set the values in `activity1` to default while starting `activity2`.

**2.** if your `activity2` is set as `noHistory=true` in `manifest`, then you can start new `activity1` while back pressed at `activity2`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, activity1.class));
}
```

**3.** You can use the options in [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) as well, only if you start `activity2` as [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int))

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` for the `activity1` after `startActivity(intent)`. After this, implement `onBackPressed` in `activity2` and start `activity1` using an `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the section before moving to Activity2